# Missing braces on \N{}

Tags: perl

I'm a newbie to Perl.  This should be simple code.  I want to move all files from a source to a destination folder.  But here's the hard part.  If data in the source exists as a duplicate, MD5 or similar hash not just name date and size, I want it to be deleted from the source.

Here's the code that I used as a test.

```
use File::Copy;

my $sourceFile = "H:\New Folder\TWH.mp4";
my $destinationFolder = "I:\New Folder\TWH.mp4";

my $destinationFile = $destinationFolder . "/" . (split("/", $sourceFile))[-1];
copy($sourceFile, $destinationFile) or die "Copy failed: $!";
if (-e $destinationFile) {
unlink $sourceFile;
}
```

Check for match between source and destination.  If the source and destination are exactly the same except metadata then delete the source.  Else, copy then remove from the source.

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes or use single quoted strings.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Compare might be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

`\` has special meaning in double-quoted string literals, so you need to escape it.

```perl
my $sourceFile = "H:\\New Folder\\TWH.mp4";
my $destinationFolder = "I:\\New Folder\\TWH.mp4";
```

Since only `\` and the delimiters needs escaping in single-quoted string literals, you could also use the following:

```perl
my $sourceFile = 'H:\New Folder\TWH.mp4';
my $destinationFolder = 'I:\New Folder\TWH.mp4';
```

Finally, since Windows accepts both `\` and `/` as the directory separator, you can also use the following:

```perl
my $sourceFile = "H:/New Folder/TWH.mp4";
my $destinationFolder = "I:/New Folder/TWH.mp4";
```

Comment: I wondered about that single quote vs double quote.

The only hangup to get past is this error

    copy($sourceFile, $destinationFile) or die "Copy failed: $!";

Comment: Are you know asking a new question, in the comments, without even saying what error you got?

Answer (score 2):

The `\N{}` sequence allows you to specify a character by its name:

```
$ perl -C -le 'print "\N{SNOWMAN}"'
☃
```

As such, when Perl see the `\N`, it expects braces and a name after it:

```
$ perl -C -le 'print "\N"'
Missing braces on \N{} at -e line 1, within string
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

$ perl -C -le 'print "\N{}"'
Unknown charname '' at -e line 1, within string
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This is different than the regex `\N` which means "not a newline" since `\n` is a newline.